# PagedList not understanding when using IQueryable of new type of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable, pagedlist

I'm using `Entity framework` and I have

```
IQueryable<Doc> docs
```

where Doc is a model appropriate to my Doc table in the database.
I want to use `Pagedlist` to have  pagination on the view,
I have to pass to the view a collection `Iqueryable<Docinfo>` where `Docinfo` is another type and the object of that type is inizialized from `Doc`,
I use it in order to avoid passing all the information of the `Doc` to the view,
`Docinfo` contains only some properties of `Doc`. 
Here is the code how I use `PagedList`

```
IPagedList<Doc> pagedDocs = docs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);
```

Now pagedDocs has the following information

```
Count: 11
FirstItemOnPage: 1
HasNextPage: true
HasPreviousPage: false
IsFirstPage: true
IsLastPage: false
LastItemOnPage: 11
PageCount: 1920
PageNumber: 1
PageSize: 11
Subset: Count = 11
TotalItemCount: 21120
```

Now I have only 11 items retriewed from the database and all of them are type of `Doc`. 
How can I create `Iqueryable<Docinfo>` from that 11 objects and give it to the pagedList as a subset?
I've tried to do something like this

```
IPagedList PagedList = pagedDocs.ToList().Select(m=>new DocInfo(m)).ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);
```

but after it `PagedList` contains the following information

```
Count: 11
FirstItemOnPage: 1
HasNextPage: false
HasPreviousPage: false
IsFirstPage: true
IsLastPage: true
LastItemOnPage: 11
PageCount: 1
PageNumber: 1
PageSize: 11
Subset: Count = 11
TotalItemCount: 11
```

As you can see, in this way I'll always have only one page on the view, because I lost the information about `PageCount`,`TotalItemCount` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PagedList using LINQ Skip and Take, but show paging using Count of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942395/pagedlist-using-linq-skip-and-take-but-show-paging-using-count-of-results)

Comment: The post is very useful, but my case is a bit different, because I know that `Pagedlist`  calls `take` and `skip` internally, my problem is  I want to create a collection of another type(`Docinfo` in my case) and pass that collection to the view.

Comment: `StaticPagedList` did the trick. Thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't just operate with DbContext without applying IPagedList

```
IUnitOfWork<YourContext> _uOf;

var context = _uOw.Context
```

by means of context you are free to use any method you want

Comment: If be honest I'm not familiar with `IUnitOfWork` interface. I'll examine it, but I think I will have to make a lot of changes in my project to get rid of `Pagedlist`